# How to map a model to Stored Procedure parameters in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a model containing around 50 properties. The properties should be mapped as parameters of a stored procedure. I had to use FromSqlRaw and pass the model as a parameter. How can I achieve this task?

Example:

```
public DummyModel
{
  public int PropertyA { get; set; }
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }
  public DateTime PropertyC { get; set; }
  // Rest removed for brevity.
}


...FromSqlRaw("exec dummy_stored_procedure @PropertyA @PropertyB @PropertyC ...", DummyModel);
```

Comment: It's generally better to simply ask how to do something than to ask what the "best" way to do something is. People answering how to do something aren't going to answer with the worst/least efficient/poorest performing methods of doing something, and if they do, the answer will be voted down soon enough.

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools

Comment: You can make your own utility function. With Reflection you examine the object and create a Parameter list based on Name, Type and Value of each property. With attributes, you can exclude some properties.